# Not getting all records except last 2 records with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having following records in my table:

**Variant:**

```
Id  RegionId   Type   Name
1   1001       Add    A1
2   1001       Diff   A2
3   1001       Mul    A3
4   1001       Diff   A4
5   1001       Mul    A5
```

**VariantsinTest**:Stores Variants in Test

```
Id  TestId  VariantId
1   1       5 
2   1       4 
3   1       3 
4   1       2 
5   1       1 
6   2       5
7   2       3
8   2       1
9   3       4
10  3       3
11  3       2
12  3       1
```

**Test:**

```
Id RegionId  Name  Run
1  1001      T1    True
2  1001      T2    True
3  1001      T3    True
```

**DataModel:**

```
public partial class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Run { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RegionId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VariantsinTest> VariantsinTest { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class VariantsinTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public int VariantId { get; set; }
        public virtual Variant Variant{ get; set; }
        public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class Variant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VariantsinTest> VariantsinTest { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I am trying to get list of tests for particular region only and for Diff type variant only with Run value as True by skipping last 2 latest tests and get all other tests but the problem is with above test records I am not getting record with **test id =1**.

**Query:**

```
 var data = (from t in context.Test
                             where t.Run == True && 
                             (t.RegionId == 1001 )
                             && t.VariantTest.Any(vt => vt.Variant.Type == "Diff")) // get test list for diff type only
                             orderby t.Id descending
                             select new 
                             {
                                 Id = t.Id,
                                 name = t.Name
                             }).Skip(2).ToList();
```

With the above query I am not getting record of 1st Test.

Comment: is `(t.RegionId == 1001 )
                             && t.VariantTest.Any(vt => vt.Variant.Type == "Diff"))` all of that true for test id=1

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Based on records in my table and records that i have given in my question it is true

Comment: But you're getting Diff only, and id 1 is Add

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre But i have purposely put condition for Diff type only.You can see in my query

Comment: Right, so I'm not seeing the issue, the record with an ID of 1 is of Add type, you are only querying Diff - so why are you confused that you are not getting 1 returned

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre:I want to get list of test which is for Diff type variants with particular region Id and with run value as true

Comment: can you test it without `.Skip(2)` and see the result ?

Comment: @Sampath:Getting all three test by removing skip method and by removing that diff condition and using skip method i am getting that 1st test record

Comment: OK,now you know the reason no ? adjust your query according.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre:Sorry actually i have given wrong test id in VariantsinTest table.Updated my question

Comment: According to your sample data, the query without skip will get only tests 1 and 3 as test 2 fails on "Diff" condition. Then when you skip 2 records, there should be empty list in the result. What is the output you get for this sample?

Comment: @wonderbell : With the sample input given in question i am getting 0 records with query

Comment: As I pointed out, 0 records is the correct result according to your condition. Because only two records match the condition and query skips 2, so 0 records are returned. Please change your sample data.

Comment: in "orderby m.Id descending" part what is "m" ?

Comment: @vlscanner:Sorry updated my question.

Comment: @Learning can you tell me in your query `&& t.VariantTest.Any(vt => vt.Variant.Type == "Diff"))` part having `vt.Variant` in it , and i think the class name is `Control` as you provide the code above. So i think either its the typo in the question you asked or thats the problematic part

Comment: @Viplock:Updated my question with correcting that mistake and yes it was a typo mistake

Comment: There are still typos in it (`VariantTest` vs `VariantsinTest`) but more importantly, its unclear what you want. Your `Test` contains 3 items. 2 of 3 items satisfy the condition `t.VariantTest.Any(vt => vt.Variant.Type == "Diff")`. You skip 2 items, you get an empty result. So far, everything looks pretty trivial, why do you expect anything different?

Comment: @grek40 :Sorry but now i understand that this query is giving me perfect output and it was mistake from my side that i didnt check the data properly